# Delete remote branch with bracket name

Tags: git, powershell

I have a remote branch named  as `qa(old_ui)`. I don't have it locally.
I used the command

```
git push origin --delete qa(old_ui)
```

but no luck. I think that is because of the brackets.

The error is `"The term 'old_ui' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

by the way, I want to use pure git commands to accomplish this.

Comment: The error message suggests you are doing this in PowerShell. It's almost always a good idea to quote names like that, did you try `--delete "qa(old_ui)"`?

Comment: I used the powershell but no working. The error is `fatal: not a git respository...`

Comment: @Hello You seem to be in the wrong directory when you execute this command. You must be in the local clone of the remote repository so you can execute the command.

Comment: @knittl, I am not sure. I check out the branch to the local and run the command. Same error

Comment: @Hello `cd` into the cloned directory before calling push: `git clone git.server.fqdn/path/to/HelloRepo.git; cd HelloRepo; git push origin --delete 'qa(old_ui)'`

Comment: It seems single quote works.@MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments from everybody. It seems like the single quotes works in the correct directory.

`git push origin --delete 'qa(old_ui)'`

Comment: Powershell is finicky about special characters. Another one that comes up from time to time in Git is that `@` is shorthand for `HEAD`, but in [powershell it must be escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61490618/184546).