# How to completely replace dev branch into master? (Without having to resolve conflicts)

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

My `master` branch is very out to date. Like 100+ commits behind `dev`, is not longer needed anymore. If I merge with dev there are many conflicts I don't need to resolve. Plus, I have created a `master-old` branch just in case. How can I make `dev` as my master without having to resolve conflicts.

I tried:

1. Destoy `master` an create it again from `dev`  (not allowed by github)
2. Rebase (It need to resolve conflicts)
3. Flag --theirs (not sure how to use it)

Comment: Delete master and rename dev?

Comment: Just reset `master` on `dev`. It's probably the simplest way, and as a bonus the branch's reflog will be preserved (which is not the case if you delete/recreate the branch).

Comment: To clarify. @RomainValeri gave half of the answer, he pointed to this question as repeated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210446/how-to-replace-local-branch-with-remote-branch-entirely-in-git. The problem of that answer is that does not explain how to `git push --force`. I found the other part of the solution here:
https://superuser.com/questions/716818/how-to-overwrite-a-branch-in-git-with-master

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard dev
git push --force
```