# Update cloned repo from remote in Eclipse?

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

New to Git but I figured out how to clone a colleague's repo in Eclipse. They made updates and now I want to pull(?) those updates but I'm getting a merge conflict (conflict with files then it lists several files). I'm ok with overwriting any local changes I made, just want it to be the same as the Git repo. I'm confused between fetch and pull, and reset vs. rebase.

Comment: Backup and then https://stackoverflow.com/a/44658551/7976758 `git fetch origin main && git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD` or `git reset --hard origin/main`, Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+make+branch+the+same+as+remote

Comment: Fetch gets the changes from the remote repository without updating your local files. Pull in addition tries to update your files. If you did some commits without pushing them in the meantime, then you can either merge (leads to a commit with two parent commits) or rebase (leads to a nice linear history) those commits. A rest changes your local files to the given state. Best practice is to work in the _Git Staging_ view. Double-click the files to see your changes. Right-click the files and choose _Replace with HEAD revision_ to discard your changes, so you will get no merge conflicts on pull.

Comment: @phd The question is not about the command line Git.